# Is blocking direct access by javascript top.location property possible?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an IFrame inside my 1st page that loads another page which I don't want it to be accessed directly. So I thought maybe I can be sure that the 2nd page is loaded inside 1st one if I check the top.location in 2nd page and do as normal if it's equal 1st page URL or remember user as hacker if it's not.

Here is the code:

**1st Page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>1st Page</title>
</head>

<iframe src="2nd Page" name="frame1" height="80%" width="100%"></iframe>

</html>
```

**2nd Page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(top.location == "1st Page URL") {
        // It's OK, Access is not direct
    } else {
        // It's not a normal access
    }
</script>
```

It seems that this code will work fine, but I'm not sure if it's foolproof or not. Maybe top.location could be spoofed (like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) or it's totally unreliable somehow. I need to be sure about that.

Comment: Keep in mind: It's very easy to turn Javascript off.

Comment: Javascript can be disabled so even if you could do this you can't prevent someone from using this URL with it.

Comment: Even if the user has JavaScript enabled, at that point it's too late to stop the client from accessing the page. It's already been sent to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use JSPs. Have your second page, the one that should never be accessed directy placed in the WEB-INF folder of your project, and then have the main page do a jsp:forward towards that resource. This way the 2nd page can never be accessed directly.

Answer (score 1):

top.location, HTTP referer and everything can be spoofed easily. There is no point of trying to build client-side security checks.

Instead, you should focusing make your code robust using sessions, etc.